# Subdomain setup in react.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, subdomain

im new to react.js
I want  to know how can i have **multiple** subdomains in react Like `subdomain.localhost:3000` 
I tried some tutorials ,when they type `subdomain.localhost.com` it takes them to default page i.e localhost.com but in my case it is taking me to `Invalid host header` .
Does anyone know how to set **multiple** subdomains in react.

Comment: subdomain.localhost.com? or subdomain.localhost:3000

Comment: Yes,my bad localhost:3000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use default host file in OS

Hosts file is a local file stored on the computer that translates domain names or NetBIOS names into an IP addresses.

in window you can find in
`drive:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc`

Problem Solve by adding
`DANGEROUSLY_DISABLE_HOST_CHECK=true`
in .env file of React Js

Comment: I have added `# 127.0.0.1       localhost` my host file in `System32\drivers\etc`
Still not working.

Comment: any desk or teamviewer ?

Comment: Not in my machine? Google meet?

Comment: https://meet.google.com/bew-arjq-vfm

Comment: Im here........

Comment: is It   working now?

Comment: Yesss....DANGEROUSLY_DISABLE_HOST_CHECK=true 
in .env and your google meet helped me alot .

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to edit your hosts file on your OS to reflect this.
127.0.0.1 [www.domain.com](http://www.domain.com)
127.0.0.1 domain.com

Comment: Ive tried this ,not working.